# Subclass of EditText isn't behaving like EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, subclass

I've written a subclass of `EditText`.  Here is that subclass:

```
package com.package.foo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FuturaEditText extends EditText{

    public FuturaEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public FuturaEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FuturaEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/futura.ttf"));
        }
    }

}
```

yet it doesn't behave like an `EditText`, but a `TextView`.  In particular, the soft keyboard isn't rising on focus and it has no `EditText` formatting.  Why?

Answer (score 5):

For completeness - from the source:

```
public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.editTextStyle);
}
```

So, if the constructor is called with no default style, it defaults to `editTextStyle`

Comment: That explains it!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

This implementation, with each constructor calling the matched `super` constructor:

```
package com.package.foo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FuturaEditText extends EditText{

    public FuturaEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/futura.ttf"));
        }
    }

    public FuturaEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/futura.ttf"));
        }
    }

    public FuturaEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/futura.ttf"));
        }
    }

}
```

works.  I can only assume that `EditText(context, attrs, 0)` is not the same as `EditText(context, attrs)`.

Comment: Duplicated code for no reason.  Of course `EditText(context, attrs, 0)` is not the same as `EditText(context, attrs)`  The correct approach is to use this(context, null) in the first constructor, and therefore bubble up the constructor chain.

Comment: That approach was the approach that caused my issue.  I wasn't calling `FuturaEditText(context)`; the layout was calling `FuturaEditText(context, attrs)` and not hitting the correct `super` constructor.

Comment: OK, I learned something there.  Please edit your post so I can undo my -1.  Any change will do.  Apologies, I was wrong.

Comment: Did this solution solve your soft keyboard not appearing issue too?

Answer (score 3):

You should not invoke the super constructor completing the missing arguments, otherwise there's no way for a client to invoke a constructor with less than 3 arguments (i.e. `super.(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`).

The second version is the correct one.